# Reading MAX31888 works with Nano, but not with ATtiny85

Tags: arduino-nano, attiny85, 1-wire

I'm using the OneWire library to try and read temperatures from a [MAX31888](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX31888.pdf) sensor using this Arduino program:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <OneWire.h>

#define RX PB4
#define TX PB3
#define OW PB0

SoftwareSerial serial(RX, TX);
OneWire ds(OW);

void setup() {
  serial.begin(19200);
  delay(1000);
  serial.println("TX_INIT");
}

void loop() {
  byte addr[8];
  if (!ds.search(addr)) {
    serial.println("No more addresses.");
    serial.println();
    ds.reset_search();
    delay(250);
    return;
  }
  serial.print("ROM =");
  for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    serial.write(' ');
    serial.print(addr[i], HEX);
  }
  delay(5E3);
}
```

When I test this on an Arduino Nano, with hardware serial instead of software, I get the output I expect:

```
ROM = 54 36 25 5 0 0 0 3C
No more addresses.
```

But when I compile and burn the same program to an Attiny85, using the internal 8 MHz clock bootloader, all I get is:

```
No more addresses.
```

What could be the issue here? I've read DS18B20 sensors just fine with the 8 MHz internal clock bootloader before.

Software & library versions used:

- Arduino IDE ver. 2.2.1
- Arduino AVR Boards core for Nano, ver. 1.8.6
- [ATTiny core](https://github.com/damellis/attiny) ver. 1.0.2
- [Onewire library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html) ver. 2.3.7

Wiring diagram for ATTiny setup:
[image: ATTINY_WIRING]

Diagram legend:

- U1: USB
- U2: ATTiny85
- U3: [MCP2221](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp2221)
- J1: OneWire header

Please note that the VUSB pin of the MCP2221 outputs a regulated 3.3V.

Comment: If your code shown also doesn't work as shown with a DS18B20 you're likely to get more help. The name and version of the Arduino core in use would help. Same for OneWire, there is not just one of these now, and there are forks of all of them. Same of SoftwareSerial assuming it isn't just part of the core you're using.

Comment: @timemage I've added version numbers and sources to my initial post for applicable software and library versions. SoftSerial is indeed part of the core in this case. The DS18B20's work just fine with this on both ATTiny and Nano, the same code reports the DS18B20's ROM just fine on both. But only the Nano reports the MAX31888 ROM, and not the ATTiny for some reason. Response on DS18B20: `ROM = 28 AD 45 73 E 0 0 E7 No more addresses.` Which seems to be correct, since the family code for DS18B20 is 0x28.

Comment: It looks like you have good details now.  Unfortunately I don't believe I have a MAX31888 to test with.  But, I'm voting it up. That is appears to top out at 3.6V makes me wonder how you've been wiring it.

Comment: @timemage Both on the ATTiny and Nano, I use 3.3V for powering the sensor. Though both microcontrollers are powered off of 5V from USB. On the Nano I use the 3.3V regulated output and on the nano I have a separate regulator for 3.3V

Comment: Does it work if you also use SoftwareSerial on the Nano?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I can try, I don't see how that would change anything since I get a serial response with SoftSerial on ATTiny when using a DS18B20, and also a failure message when either nothing, or a MAX31888 is connected.

Comment: @EdgarBonet SoftSerial works fine on Nano